# Running an RSpec test suite against a TimescaleDB database with Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, timescaledb

I have a Rails 4.2.11.1 application that I am trying to use with a TimescaleDB database.

I've solved the majority of the issues already (using the `composite_primary_keys` gem to get around Timescale's restriction that unique indexes should always include the table's timestamp column).

This has my application fully functional, but my test suite fails whenever I try to write to the Timescale table, with the following error:

```
PG::FeatureNotSupported: ERROR:  invalid INSERT on the root table of hypertable "events"
HINT:  Make sure the TimescaleDB extension has been preloaded.
```

As far as I can tell, Rails is not enabling the extension within the test database; this applies whichever schema dumping mode I'm using (either `:sql` or `:ruby`). Connecting to the database manually with `bundle exec rails dbconsole`, I can see that the extension is enabled.

I'm not sure whether this is a bug with my code, with Timescale, or with Rails, but it's stopping me from being able to ship this change.

I'm hoping that someone else has come across this scenario before and is able to help!

Comment: Can you see the connection string from Ruby to PostgreSQL to see, which database it connects? Have you tried to connect from another tool and to try to insert into TimescaleDB table? Can you see the actual INSERT statement?
You can also ask TimescaleDB community at Slack if somebody there went through your issue.

Comment: Did you create a migration that enables the extension so that its listed in `schema.rb`?

Comment: @max Yes, that's been done.

Comment: @k_rus I've got some dumps of the INSERT statement, yeah. And the connection string too. I've joined the TimescaleDB Slack to see if anyone there can help.

Comment: @SteveHill did you figure this out?

Comment: @AxelTheGerman I did not - we delayed the project for moving to Timescale until after we complete a move to Rails 5.2/6.0. Figured the underlying database functionality in Rails might have improved a lot in that timeframe.

Comment: Thanks @SteveHill! You probably want to follow an issue I just filed https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/1916 - currenly it doesn't seem possible to make TimescaleDB work with Rails schema management. I also started a separate discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61874638/unable-to-use-timescaledb-in-rails-test-environment - current workaround seems to be to use the ruby schema and recreate the hyper tables in your test DB - I added this to my `test_helper.rb`

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that the extension is enabled for your test database?

Try running:
`RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rails dbconsole`

If you wrote a migration to enable the extension I would have expected that it would run against your test database as well, unless you've specifically run it only against development.

Comment: Yes, I've done exactly this. I would have expected the same, but there's definitely something weird going on here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Rails 6.0.2.2 / TimescaleDB 1.7.0 (On Minitest).

The problem was solved, when I switched from sql schema dump back to ruby schema dump.

```ruby
config.active_record.schema_format = :ruby # (in application.rb)
```

Apparently, the schema dump of the sql format contained errors/was partial, and preparing from it introduced the error (db:test:clone).

Hope it helps your case.

Comment: Unfortunately my upvote is already locked in, otherwise I'd take it back.
That doesn't work at all, all it does is that the raw SQL to create the hyper table is not present in `schema.rb` and therefore no hyper table, no problem inserting into it :(

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the schema dump file is missing is missing the extension enable command,

If `config.active_record.schema_format = :ruby` then `schema.rb` will contain `enable_extension "timescaledb"`

If `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` then `structure.sql` will contain 
`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb WITH SCHEMA public;`

If these lines exist in your schema dumps, you might have to do a clean restore of the test db schema

```rb
# take care with dropping your test db, make sure the database is configured correctly
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:schema:load # RAILS_ENV=test rake db:structure:load if :sql
```

You should then be able to run your test and the extension will be enabled through the schema restore process above.